# Overload EF Validation with Custom class

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2

I m using Entity Framework, and have one view which is strongly type view model of type tblAuthorMaster. On Post ModelState returns me following error :

```
The value '0' is not valid for Status.
```

Here Status is of boolen datatype in DB/EF and on view it's dropdown (TEXT="active/inactive", VALUE="1/0"), so whenever i post my form i used to get the above error message.

I have tried some solution to overcome with this issue but it seems not wotking properly.

Following is my code base:

Here tblAuthorMaster is EF Class and AuthorModel is my Custom Class, which i m using for some custom validation and other stuff.

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(AuthorModel))]
    public partial class tblAuthorMaster { }

    public class AuthorModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public bool Status { get; set; }        

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work properly the VALUE in the dropdown must be `true/false` and not `1/0`. Since you haven't shown how you are generating your doropdown it is hard to help but it might look something like this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Status,
    new[] 
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = "active" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = "inactive" },
    }
) %>
```

Also what's the point of using a dropdown with 2 possible values? HTML provides you with checkboxes for this purpose:

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Status) %>
```

And a final remark: what you call a *view model* in your question is not a view model at all. It's an autogenerated EF domain model. View models are classes tat you specifically design for the requirements of a given view, they are not autogenerated by some wizard.

Comment: Setting value as true/false is working fine, but why not with 1/0.

Comment: Because in .NET a boolean type can have values `true` or `false`, not `1` and `0`, contrary to some other languages such as javascript for example. When the default model binder attempts to parse the value from the request to a boolean it fails and adds the error message to the `ModelState`.

Comment: Thanks Darin actually i was looking for some other option, which include some changes in my AuthorModel class. Can u suggest something like that ???

Comment: Yes, use an `Integer` instead of a `Boolean` if you want to bind to `1` or `0`. That would of course be a very wrong approach.